# Analysis Qual Prep Question

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a hard time solving the following problem. Any help would be wonderful. Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be measurable and $\int_{[0, 1]}fdm = 1$.  Is it true that there exists a continuous function $g:[0,1]→[0,\infty)$ with $g \leq f$ $a.e.$ and $\int_{[0,1]}gdm>0?$

Comment: What is $f$ and how does $E$ play into this?

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, if you take for $f$ a function such that in any open set, the zero set of $f$ is not null, for instance the characteristic function of a [fat cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set) (scaled appropriately), then there is no such $g$ (it should be easy to see why).

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $C$ be a [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set), say of measure $1/2$, and let $f=2\chi_{C}$ where $\chi_C$ is the indicator function of $C$. Then $\int_{[0,1]}f\mathrm{d}m=1$. Suppose $g\leq f$ a.e. and $\int_{[0,1]}g\mathrm{d}m>0$. Then we have some interval $I$ on which $g>0$ a.e., so $I\setminus C$ has measure $0$. But $C$ is missing an interval from every interval, so $I\setminus C$ has positive measure, a contradiction.